# Does a black dragon's Corrupt Water (Su) affect Alchemists' extracts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

Talking with my friends about the "alchemy" of the Alchemist class, we're fighting about the alchemist extracts. Look at this description:

> Extracts are the most varied of the three. In many ways, they behave like spells in **potion** form

OK, now, we can assume that extracts are potions in some way, right? Now, look at this ability from the black dragon:

> **Corrupt Water (Su)**: Once per day an adult or older black dragon can stagnate 10 cubic feet of still water, making it foul and unable to support water-breathing life. The ability spoils liquids containing water. Liquid-based magic items (such as potions) and items in a creature's possession must succeed on a Will save (DC equal to the dragon's frightful presence) or become ruined.

Whoa! My alchemist occupies a space of 5 feet, and his extracts "are" potions. Now, he make a will save against this ability or not? Two to four alchemists can be affected by this ability?

Comment: I must remember, if I ever play an alchemist, to specify ahead of time that all of my extracts use a pure alcohol base. And also to play a dwarf.

Comment: @GMJoe Go with oil instead. Even “pure” alcohol has water in it because distillation has an upper limit.

Answer (score 3):

RAW: **Yes.**

Extracts are "Liquid-based magic items" (potions are simply one example).

1. They are Liquid as you are specifically described as "drinking" them.
2. And they are magic items: "An alchemist can create three special types of magical items—extracts, bombs, and mutagens"

So as per the rules all extracts on your person would be affected by **Corrupt Water** and would need to succeed on a Will Save or become ruined.

Side-note: Interestingly, Bombs also specifically mention liquid and Mutagens are "brewed", so at least by RAW, Corrupt Water could devastate any Alchemist it was cast on.

Comment: Most of these comments should probably be deleted. But here is a link to a forum thread discussing this topic: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2qcv4?Black-Dragon-Corrupt-Water-Ability-vs